# Permute subsystems of a matrix?

Tags: matrix, tensors, permutation

Suppose I have a matrix $M$ acts on the space $\mathbb C^4\otimes \mathbb C^2\otimes \mathbb C^4\otimes \mathbb C^3$. Is there a method to permute the 2nd subsystem of $M$ and the 4th subsystem of $M$? In other words, I have a matrix $M=A_1\otimes A_2\otimes A_3\otimes A_4$, how can I permute the second and the fourth subsystem of $M$ to get $A_1\otimes A_4\otimes A_3\otimes A_2$ when I only have access to $M$ while don't have access to $A_i$?

For example, I have a matrix $$M=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
how can I switch the first and second subsystems permitted the first system is of dimension $2$ and the second system is of dimension $2$. In index form, $M$ can be written as $$\left( \begin{matrix}
    m_{00,00}&      m_{00,01}&      m_{00,10}&      m_{00,11}\\
    m_{01,00}&      m_{01,01}&      m_{01,10}&      m_{01,11}\\
    m_{10,00}&      m_{10,01}&      m_{10,10}&      m_{10,11}\\
    m_{11,00}&      m_{11,01}&      m_{11,10}&      m_{11,11}\\
\end{matrix} \right) .$$ The element $m_{00,10}$ after switching should be in place $00,01$. Anyway, the transformed $M$ in numerical form should be
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 3 & 2 & 4 \\
 9 & 11 & 10 & 12 \\
 5 & 7 & 6 & 8 \\
 13 & 15 & 14 & 16 \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$

Comment: You do not have access to $A_i$. What is known then, dimensions?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? `myM[i1_,i2_,i3_,i4_]:= M[i1,i4,i3,i2]`

Comment: @yarchik Thank you for your comment! I have access to $M$.

Comment: @DanielHuber Thank you for your comment, but I think it's not. I have $M$ in matrix form which can, but I don't know what $A_i$ is, be written as `KroneckerProduct[A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4]`. When I have access to the matrix $M$, how can I switch the two subsystems $A_2$ and $A_4$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution is as follows. The core idea is to utilize the `TensorTranspose` function. Let's clarify things using the example in the original question. I first reshape the matrix using

```mathematica
testmat = ArrayReshape[mat, {2, 2, 2, 2}];
```

Then I switch the first and second subsystems using `TensorTranspose`

```mathematica
testmat = TensorTranspose[testmat, {2, 1, 4, 3}];
```

Finally, I recover the matrix from `testmat` using reshape function

```mathematica
testmat = ArrayReshape[testmat, {4, 4}];
```

The code above is summarized as follows

```mathematica
mat = ArrayReshape[Range@16, {4, 4}];
testmat = ArrayReshape[mat, {2, 2, 2, 2}];
testmat = TensorTranspose[testmat, {2, 1, 4, 3}];
testmat = ArrayReshape[testmat, {4, 4}];
testmat // MatrixForm
```